# How to use C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

For my school assignment I have to make a reservationsystem for a hotel.
The thing is that I have to make the code without the UI (never done this before).
I have to add the UI later. Each UI should be able to be used with my code.

Now I have a class called `Secretary`
The `Secretary` is able to make a `Reservation`.
I have this method in the class `Secretary` :

```
public void CheckIn()
        {
            Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
            reservation.ReservationDate1 = //info from a textbox
        }
```

Now I know that I should connect everything when my UI is ready, but what is the best way to tell my code that he should get the information from the textbox when the textbox isn't there yet???

Comment: use MVVM pattern to separate front end and back end logic. you need a view model. you get and set your items from and into view model properties. later you bind UI into that view model.

Comment: How come you have an assignment for something you have not done at school?  I would suggest starting off looking at MVVM.  Luckily the other week my good mate Pete started a series of articles of this off over at CodeProject.  He takes you through everything without WPF.  http://web4.codeproject.com/Articles/1163180/Bare-Metal-MVVM-Where-The-Code-Meets-The-Road-Part

Comment: @Gigitex A textbox should bind to a string.  The string needs to be a property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  I recommend you try it with a UI just to see how it works.

Comment: I would personally start off writing a View Model using some TDD.  Where TDD would involve a simple set of Unit Tests.  Pretend that the "UI" is your tests methods. You will fathom how things work.  But I suggest the background reading I linked to.

Answer (score 3):

i would suggest you start by reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx)

now as for what you have to do then
first you will need to model your data

```
public class Reservation
{
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public void Save(){/*Copy entry to DB, webservice, file, etc*/}
    public void Delete(){/*delete entry from DB, webservice, file, etc*/}
    //ect

}
```

as you can see you now have a list of what is required for a reservation, and functionality that will persist your data

next you need a ViewModel

```
public class ReservationViewModel:INotifyPropertyCHanged
{
    public Reservation Reservation{get;set;} //Link to model
    private DateTime _Date;

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Date, value); }
    }
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Name, value); }
    }
    public void SetProperty<T>(ref T store, T value,[CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        store = value;
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedArgs(name);
    }
    public void Save(){/*validate, copy over model values call models save*/}
    public void Cancel(){/*change VM values back to Model values*/}
    public void Delete(){/*validate, call models delete*/}
    //ect
}
```

at this point you can stop as you have defined the data and behaviour of the system, though i would suggest adding a testing project to run your code and check it works

when you get to your View
you would just bind to your ViewModel and the rest is done for you

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Name}/>
```

Comment: Do I have to make a viewmodel for each class?

Comment: Also it doesn't recognize  public Reservation Reservation{get;set;} //Link to model

Comment: you need a viewModel for for every view that needs linking to a model

Comment: That error is saying that you can't use a private or internal class in a public property, i would guess that in your reservation class you have forgotten the public in front of the class

Comment: also remember you only want to default Reservation to new Reservation() when you are creating a new one

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVM with a `ViewModel`, but if you just want a method ready to accept input when you design the UI, you can make `Checkin()` take a string parameter so it's `Checkin(string value)` and assign value to `ReservationDate1`.

```
        public void CheckIn(string val)
        {
            Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
            reservation.ReservationDate1 = val;
        }
```

This is an exercise in keeping your logic and your UI nice and separate.  A little more tightly coupled, but doable, would be this:

```
        public void CheckIn(TextBox tb)
        {
            Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
            reservation.ReservationDate1 = tb.Text;
        }
```

Comment: I know.  That's why I said OR.  I see how that can be misconstrued, I'll edit the post.